# Why are the search results from Microsoft Graph APIs (OneDrive Search driveItem.search) and Sharepoint Online Web different?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using Microsoft Graph APIs (driveItem.search) to search the files those user can access on Sharepoint Online. But when we open the Sharepoint Online site and search at that site, the search's result from Sharepoint Online site and the search's result from API return is different.
Example:

The keyword that we are testing is "safety access" (including parenthesis)
Here is the result from Sharepoint Online site:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfc2l.png)

Here is the result from APIs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tP5S.png)

Can anyone tell me why is it different like that?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: You can currently search only message and person collections. 
>   https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/b!05kpQIVuAkebEbnq3ftalG9eKBXqLXRJiiiQGZjVlDqML5T888BfS4YjkXMj9Exl/microsoft.graph.search(q='"Test"')` will ignore the search parameter so you will see the following in the result, it just list all drive items in the site:

```
 "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)"
```

Meanwhile, the query in SharePoint site itself just iterate over a specific document library.

Comment: It is not true. Right now we are using graph api https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/drives/b!_rJP3E45vk2mwwUmwzYTi-j4YxNHt5REgaC72xF5j5aS8Y1YJixLTJUjsQ0jE3Sj/microsoft.graph.search(q='"safety access"') for search items on DriveID with keyword like this. The result still return data. But when we test with Sharepoint Online site, the search result return different with API's search result.

Comment: I know the api will return data. but even if you replace the q="safety access" to q="test" or so, it should also return data.

Comment: From what I am understand now, the Search API ignores the parenthesis and space characters.

Comment: Can u give me the evidence for your conclusion?

Comment: Pls pay attention to the official Graph docs: Note: You can currently search only message and person collections. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter. But you want to search on drives.

Comment: I dont use the param like you. I use this API https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_search

Comment: My query is based on your description and official documents :https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_search. The query param is for alll Graph APIs, no matter you use which. Pay attention again for the note in the official docs. Odata query is different for each supported product.  And your demo image is not for drive root, which is in the official docs too.